# How to get value of list outside its scope

Tags: node.js

I have defined a list like this :
let retail_price_appveh = []
It is updated within the function like this:

```
axios({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
       headers: {
         Cookie: cookie,
       },
     })
       .then((res) => {
           
           
         retail_price_appveh.push(xpath.fromPageSource(res.data).findElements('//table[@class="list-view-12"]//tr//td//div')[1].getText().trim());
        })
```

When I print it inside it seems fine but when I print it outside it is null. How do I retain its values once the scope ends?

Comment: It's a matter of timing.  The ONLY place you can use that asynchronous result is inside the `.then()` handler or pass it to a function you call from there.  It's a matter of timing.  Anywhere outside the `.then()` handler, the code gets executed BEFORE the result is available so the variable is just empty.  It's not a matter of scope - it's a matter of timing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are calling an async function and before assigning value to it you are printing its value. async function don't wait on the thread.
Convert the axios to async await and your problem will be solved.

```
let retail_price_appveh = []
const res = await axios({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
       headers: {
         Cookie: cookie,
       },
     })
retail_price_appveh.push(xpath.fromPageSource(res.data).findElements('//table[@class="list-view-12"]//tr//td//div')[1].getText().trim());
console.log(retail_price_appveh)
```